# GRASS workflow for volume calculation

Tags: grass-gis

i am attempting a volume calculation using the route of 2 dems (upper and lower) and trying to subtract the difference.

workflow as follows: 
A. rasterise vector contours (v.to.rast.attr)

B. create 2 dems (r.surf.contour)

C-D. create and rasterise vector overlay (in prep for mask) (v.to.rast.attr)

this is where it goes **undone**:

E. create mask (r.mask) - mask the regions in 4 outside of the polygon(s) with a '0' null value and those inside the polygon with a '1' value (indicating the area to be processed).

F: calculate area (r.surf.area)
G: calculate volume r.volume or r.topidx

OR

F1: raster algebra (r.mapcalculator in grass) // raster calculator in qgis (demA - demB)

Is this an appropriate workflow or what would an appropriate workflow look like (with associated r./v/g. steps)?

Comment: What do you mean "goes undone"?? I think you should add two more steps to E: `r.null <your mask> setnull=0 ` to make sure that the areas outside of the polygon are NULL and *not* 0. Also be sure to do `g.region -p rast=<your mask>`

Comment: undone = workflow stops or breaks down -  cannot get past this step.

Comment: Can you try what I mentioned? Make sure the raster has only values 1 or NULL, and set the region to this raster.

Comment: @Micha: done! works nicely! Thank you! 

Except i have this annoying problem - if i quit application and then go back into the file, the mask changes and the null area becomes one of the mask areas (mask has non-connected 4-part area component)

Comment: @Micha: im also a bit confused about r.volume. to effectively employ this method, one needs to have performed r.clump. however, the clump output does not cover the entire extent of my mask. is this normal?

Comment: @Micha: what would be an alternate workflow to calculate the volume between the two DEM's? DEM1-DEM2 = exactly what i set it at.

Comment: Not sure I understand where r.volume and clumps are relevant to your problem. But if you do `(DEM1-DEM2)*cell_resolution` you will get the "cut/fill" volume between two elevation raster.